# AJAX call to PHP page, no error_log();

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

When my front end made an AJAX call with the following JS code:

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open("POST", (window.location.origin + "/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/um-jogging-platform/core/umjp-removeData.php"), true);
xhttp.send();
```

The call was made to the umjp-removeData.php file which looks as follows:

```
<?php

error_log('test');
echo 1 + 1;
```

When I inspected the file which I got back I was that result of the calculation, 2. However, to my suprise I didn't observe the log from the `error_log('test')`.

What is causing this?

Comment: what is `error_log` set to in php.ini? Is it writable?

Comment: error_log ="c:/wamp64/logs/php_error.log"  do you need any more info? I'm myself not too familiar in php configurations.

Comment: is it logging anything? when was the last log entry?

Comment: Not logging anything with AJAX, when I normally execute the file it logs

Comment: right so the log IS writable then?

Comment: What do you mean with log is writable? It does log in some occasions yes, only in this specifc occasion with AJAX it doesn't work